# API to get o365 group conversation/thread/post delta through Graph/EWS API?

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am searching for an API to query delta for o365 group conversation/conversation threads/ posts, but don't see it available in graph or EWS. Any idea?

I have tried "groups/delta" but it gives group attributes change, like membership, but not the conversation/thread/post delta.

Answer (score 0):

That Graph doesn't currently have support that this in either v1 or Beta, In EWS you should be able to use SyncFolderItems https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/syncfolderitems-operation but this is just low level data access and sync.